# Optimize firebase retrieve data in java

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase

In my android studio app, I have these 2 button (but1 and but2), which overwrite the button text with a data from my firebase database. The code bellow works fine, but there is a small delay when you go on the page to overwrite the 2 values... I am wondering how can I get rid of this small button writing delay when opening this page. Should I put this code at an other place (not onViewCreated) or is there a way with firebase to merge the 2 event listener in one newValueListener to reduce delay? Or is there a way in my xml layout to get a database child value without a delay?

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        final Button but1 = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        final Button but2 = view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
       

        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                lightOn = dataSnapshot.child("lights").child("light_on").getValue().toString();
                lightOff = dataSnapshot.child("lights").child("light_off").getValue().toString();

                String styleText =
                        "</font> </small>" + "<br/>"
                        + "<small> <font color= #ffffff'>" + "lights close at: " + lightOff
                        +"</font> </small>" + "<br/>"
                        + "<small> <font color= #ffffff'>" + "lights open at: " + lightOn
                        +"</font> </small>";

                but1.setText((Html.fromHtml(styleText)));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        Query lastchild = mDatabase.child("colors").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);

        lastchild.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String colortime = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                String styleText2 = "<font-size:9vw> <font color='#ffffff'>"
                        + "Color value: " + "</font> </small>"  + "<br/>"
                        + "<small> <font color= #ffffff'>" + colortime + "</font> </small>";

                but2.setText((Html.fromHtml(styleText2)));
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            } });

    }
```

Comment: Since that's a query passing by internet up to the server  and back. Delay will always exist and will be according to the speed connection, answer time of the server and maybe if it is rainy or not. Just keep the last color queried in share preference and load the last one known. In parallel make your request to firebase and update the view with an animation from the current color to the received color and it will be smooth for the user.

Comment: That seems like a good solution, not sure how to do a share preference though